# Android: Image is too big when using canvas drawBitmap

Tags: android

So here is what my app is doing:

1. I have a camera preview.
2. I have an overlay image on top of this camera preview.
3. When I capture the image I combine both the captured image and the overlay.
4. I display the combined imaged on an imageview.

However, the overlay is way too big when it's displayed on the imageview.

The overlay image is displayed perfectly when on the camera preview. It looks like the canvas.drawBitmap is scaling it somehow but I want to keep the original size.

IMPORTANT: This works fine on a Samsung S3, the issue occurs when using a Moto G.
Here's some of the code:

```
protected PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        cameraPreview.getCamera().stopPreview();

        Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        cameraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0, 0, cameraBitmap.getWidth(),   cameraBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        //Get the overlay image
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageview.buildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap overlayImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageview .getDrawingCache());

        Bitmap mutableBitmap = cameraBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        //Here is where I combine both images by drawing the overlay onto the captured bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlayImage , 0 , canvas.getHeight() - overlayImage.getHeight(), paint);

        //Here is where i set the image so that you can view the finished result - the combined image - but the overlay image is way too big!
        ImageView capturedView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedImageView);
        capturedView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
```

Comment: read the docs : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: use getmetrics method to get the size of your display or get the dimen of the image view where u display the TOO big thing and scale it down according to the docs so that post scale, bmp will match your imageview

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The solution was to forget about the canvas altogether and just get a screenshot of capturedView since it already had the captured image and the overlay on it.

Also, I had make sure to bring the overlay to front before getting the screenshot of capturedView.

```
        // This is the imageview where I first display the 
        // image which was captured from the camera.
        capturedView.bringToFront(); 

        // This is the overlay imageview, 
        // by bringing this in front of the capturedView 
        // I can take a screenshot of it and get both the captured 
        // image and the overlay image.
        imageview.bringToFront(); 
        capturedView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        capturedView.buildDrawingCache();

        // And now you have a bitmap with both images combined :-)
        combinedBitmap = capturedView.getDrawingCache();
```